# Can I verify the existence of a specific property in a JSON object using Compose and If blocks on Logic App?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I'm creating my first logic app and I'm totally blind so sorry for no screenshots and because I will use the Azure Logic App's code programming.

Told that, in one of the steps I retrieve a JSON object like:

```
{
  "email": "donald.duck@waltdisney.com",
  "phone number": "+123 321 111 333"
  "fields": [
    {
      "description": "name",
      "value": "Mickey",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "description": "first name",
      "value": "Donald",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "description": "last name",
      "value": "Duck",
      "id": 3
    },
    {
      "description": "age",
      "value": "1",
      "id": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

From this object I should compose a new object like:

```
{
  "email": "donal.duc@waltdisney.com",
  "first name": "Donald",
  "last name": "Duck"
}
```

and stop.

Now, I'm doing a foreach for the "fields" to retrieve only first name and last name and this is the code snippet:

```
// this works correctly:
"Compose": {
    "inputs": {
        "@{item()['description']}": "@{item()['value']}"
    },
    "runAfter": {},
    "type": "Compose"
},
"condition": {
    "actions": {
// this works correctly
        "set_variable": {
            "inputs": {
                "name": "Result-fields",
                "value": "@outputs('Union_Compose')"
            },
            "runAfter": {
                "Union_Compose": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "SetVariable"
        },
// this works correctly
        "Union_Compose": {
            "inputs": {
                "result": "@{union(variables('Result-fields'), outputs('Compose'))}"
            },
            "runAfter": {},
            "type": "Compose"
        }
    },
// I tried different conditions:
// body('Compose') contains "first name" or "last name": result: everytime false
// body('Compose')['first name'] or body('Compose')['last name'] not equals null result: everytime true
// body('Compose')['first name'] or body('Compose')['last name'] equals "*" (as wild card) but the result is everytime false!
    "expression": {
        "or": [
            {
                "contains": [
                    "@{body('Compose')}",
                    "first name"
                ]
            },
            {
                "contains": [
                    "@{body('Compose')}",
                    "last name"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "runAfter": {
        "Compose": [
            "Succeeded"
        ]
    },
    "type": "If"
}
```

but the condition is even true!
Can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 1):

I hope you don't mind but I've tried to offer another approach ...

[image: Flow]

#### Steps

**Initialize My Object** - This is just your data as provided in the question.

**Filter For First Name** - Here, you're getting the item that corresponds to the `first name` property.

From Expression = `variables('My Object')['fields']`

Left Hand Side Expression = `item()['description']`

**Filter For Last Name** - Same as the previous step (first name) but with the different right hand side value.

**Initialize New Object** - This is where you tie it all together.  This is the overall code for the `value` ...

```
{
  "email": @{variables('My Object')['email']},
  "first name": @{first(body('Filter_For_First_Name'))?['value']},
  "last name": @{first(body('Filter_For_Last_Name'))?['value']}
}
```

#### Result

[image: Result]

Comment: thanks for your answer but, if I understood correttly your approach, the idea is on the first step recreate an object with all pair "description": "value" and than filter from it, if it is correct, I can't do that because the real object contains over 28 parameters and when I tried something like that the Logic App went in error because the variables can't can't be so big.

Comment: So hang on, did you not provide the JSON that we can work with to come up with the answer then?  If not, have you got the original payload you're trying to transform?  I'm a little confused.  That JSON at the top, you said that's what you're using to transform from, correct?

Comment: No, the real object returned from the http call contains on the first level 8 parameters, on the second level 6 and on the third 28! I wrote an example of the second and third level to explain the structure of the object. Any way your suggestion was useful because, at the end, to resolve the problem I changed the logic!

Comment: I have no idea what you mean but sure. In future though, when you ask a question, you shouldn’t lead the audience into an answer that follows your approach because ultimately, your approach may be less efficient. So next time, provide the proper JSON because in your answer below, those questions about if something exists or is empty are all possible.

Answer (score 0):

Thankfully to @Skin the solution that I found is: change the logic!
As I wrote, the first step was create an object, for all fields, with "description" as key and "value" as value but I didn't find any condition, in an "If" block of an azure logic app, that could check the existence of the key "first name" and "last name" or check when its are empty!

The final solution that I found is:
First check if "description" is equal "First name" or "last name" and then go forward with other operations if it is true!
It is not the real answer to my question but I hope that this solution can help someone that will be blocked by someting like my situation!